# Issue on Adding Comma After Second Append and so on

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L9psvdvL/) and let me know how I can add comma not for the first append.

What I have is an HTML like this

```
<select id="selectBox" class="sel">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>

<select id="selectBox" class="sel">
    <option>option 4</option>
    <option>option 5</option>
    <option>option 6</option>
</select>

<select id="selectBox" class="sel">
    <option>option 7</option>
    <option>option 8</option>
    <option>option 9</option>
</select>


<input id="copyBtn" type="button" value="copy" />

<textarea id="output">

</textarea>
```

In Js what I have is:

```
$(".sel").on("change", function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $("#output").append(", " + selected);
});
```

But as you can see the append is applying comma before all selections even the first one!

Comment: ID attributes should be unique. You should differentiate, or remove them if you don't need them in your css/js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether any value is present before adding `,`

```
var $op = $("#output")
$(".sel").on("change", function () {
    var selected = $(this).val(),
        op = $op.val().trim();
    $op.val((op ? op + ", " : '') + selected);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tv249qb3/1/)

Comment: Thanks Arun I just wondering what is taking care of append() in your code?! Besides the alert is returning an empty box now!

Comment: @Suffii .val() not .text() - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tv249qb3/3/ - The previous implementation is slightly buggy as if you change a select twice there will be multiple selections

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
$(".sel").on("change", function(){
    var selected = [];
    $(".sel").each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).val());
    });
    $("#output").val(selected.join(", "));
});
```

Please check the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9psvdvL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Check textarea `val()` for adding first element

```
$(".sel").on("change", function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    var str;
    if($("#output").val().trim() === ''){ str = selected; }
    else { str = ", " + selected; } 
    $("#output").append(str);
});
```

Or a way which is easier to maintain for deletion: have an array and use `join()`

```
var selectedItems = [];
$(".sel").on("change", function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if(selectedItems.indexOf(selected) >= 0){
         selectedItems.push(selected);
    }
    $("#output").append(selectedItems.join(', '));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a solution, instead of binding change on all ".sel", loop on ".sel" first then bind change on each of them, but get the index of each ".sel", and if it is 0 (first element), alter the text where the comma will not be included.

This is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9psvdvL/3/).

```
$(".sel").each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("change", function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        var appendText = index == 0 ? selected : (", " + selected);
        $("#output").append(appendText);
    });
});
```

Please note that I have not altered any logic in your original code, and instead I have focused on the specific behavior that you strive to fix/implement.